# make timestamps in YouMax 2.0 use Time Ago

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it was possible to use [Time Ago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to replace the timestamp function in [YouMax 2.0](http://www.codehandling.com/2013/03/youmax-20-complete-youtube-channel-on.html?m=1), as YouMax’s timestamps are only expressed in months and years.

Comment: You can also try the [Youmax 7.0](http://codecanyon.net/item/youmax-youtube-channel-on-your-website/10065614) version which already has timestamps with "just now", "hours ago", "days ago", "months ago", "years ago" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I’m sure it’s possible, but it doesn’t seem as easy as setting an option when you initialize YouMax. You probably have to edit the code of YouMax – find the part where it writes the time, then change that code to call Time Ago. The code is distributed in minimized form, so you would have to use a beautifier like [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to make the code remotely readable. Search for `"month"` in the code to find the relevant part.

Another method, though much harder, is to let YouMax write its widget, then use AJAX in your own code to load each video’s page, scrape the time, format it with Time Ago, and overwrite the existing time in the widget.